# session_start() maximum execution time XAMPP

Tags: php, xampp, session-variables

I'm running a WordPress installation on XAMPP. Some files are using sessions, and I notice that any file that has session_start() will load endlessly. I always placed session_start() at the very top of the php files that are using sessions, but it still loads forever. What's up?

Answer (score 0):

Does the page actually load or does it just take a long time? If it never loads, maybe check the logs for errors to write to disk. The session_start() function required apache to write a bit of data. Could it be a permissions issue?

Comment: Now it seems to be running without getting the error about maximum execution time. It seems to now be just taking forever to return every request.

Comment: It loads. Just takes forever.

Answer (score 0):

Just search the below line in your `php.ini` file located at `c:\xampp\php\php.ini` to fix the issue. Change the value to `1` from `0`.

```
use_only_cookies=1
```

Comment: Please be more elaborative with your answer.